# How can i read from JSON file in EJS?

Tags: node.js, json, ejs

I have a data.JSON file and i'm requiring it like this

```
 <!--server.js-->
 const express = require("express");
 const app = express();
 const data = require('data.json');


 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// serve static files from the folders
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
   var dataToEJS ={
      title : "Magma Travel",
      data : data
      }
      res.render("index", dataToEJS); 
     });
```

In my template .ejs i set the variable like this:

```
<title> <%= configuration.title%> </title>
```

and my JSON file is this

```
{
    "configuration": {
    "title": "Magma Travel",
    "subtitle": "Agenzia Viaggi"
 }
```

this is directory [this is directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZkIr.png)

why when I start my server.js he can't find the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
  res.render('index',{myData: dataToEJS});
<title> <%= myData.data.configuration.title%> </title>
```